# Sed running recursively and can't re-allocate memory

Tags: sed

i am new to sed commands..... and i am trying some commands but it is always getting in some recursion..... and in some cases it says "can't re-allocate memory"

**Infinite Recursive Output:**

```
echo -e 'hell\nnautanki\nwtf' | sed -e '1h;1!H;$!d' -e 'x;l;D'
```

**Memory Re-allocation problem:**

```
echo -e 'hell\nnautanki\nwtf'| sed -e '1h;1!H;$!d' -e 'x;D'
```

Errors out with:

```
sed: couldn't re-allocate memory
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do something that perverse????  It's the "sed" equivalent of an infinite loop, consuming all available RAM and CPU.  If you're serious about learning "sed", look here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html.  If you're just playing "let's see if we can break the OS" ... not interested.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just wanted to see the working of 'D' command @Tichomodroma...

Answer (score 3):

As noted by *paulsm4*, you've created an infinite loop which allocates memory on each iteration, the first example is just a slower version of the second, because of the printing, it will eventually also error with `couldn't re-allocate memory`.

Let's break it down:

```
1h
1!H
$!d
```

Will save all input into hold space, note that `d` starts the next cycle.

The last two commands `x; D` are only executed when the last line is reached. This is the situation just before these will be run:

```
PS: wtf
HS: hell\nnautanki\nwtf
```

`x` swaps them and `D` removes `hell\n` and restarts cycle because pattern space isn't empty. The `1!H` will is executed on the new pattern space, resulting in:

```
PS: nautanki\nwtf
HS: wtf\nnautanki\nwtf
```

i.e. a slight increase in memory usage on every iteration.

With two lines of input, the situation is a bit different:

```
PS: nautanki
HS: hell\nnautanki
```

Becomes:

```
PS: nautanki
HS: nautanki
```

And so on to infinity.

One line of input results in:

```
PS: hell
HS: hell
```

Then:

```
PS: 
HS: hell
```

And so terminates.

Comment: Thanks Thor.....for such a good explanation.... I was just experimenting with those commands to have better understanding of such a powerful tool....